# SQL Sum count 2 or more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query and my goal to sum 2 or more columns

```
SELECT field, sum(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT column1 as field, count(*) as cnt
  FROM table
  GROUP BY column1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT column2 as field, count(*) as cnt
  FROM table
  GROUP BY column2
  order by field asc
)
GROUP BY field
ORDER BY sum(cnt) DESC
```

I got error and someone can see the wrong line. Thank you.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Remove the `order by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query would more easily be expressed as:

```
select v.field, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (column1), (column2)) v(field)
group by v.field
order by count(*) desc;
```

This would also likely have better performance.

Note:  As I say in my comment, your version would work if you just removed the `order by` in the subquery.

Comment: Great works. But I still want to know why my query does not work? I did remove order by still got error

Comment: @qphan Because the **inner** order by clause is not syntactically legal. I would refer to the name of the derived table in your query but it is missing - another syntax error.